# Read len bytes of a file at offset and write it to FILETIME

Tags: c++, c, binary, sequential, fseek

Is there any possibility to read sth from a binary file when knowing only the size of the element that should be red and the offset (in hexa)?

For example, if I want to read a FILETIME variable of 8 bytes, that has offset 0x001C, how do I approach this is C or C++?

I tried

```
fseek(pFile, 0x001C, SEEK_SET);
FILETIME* temp =(FILETIME*) malloc(sizeof(FILETIME));
fscanf(pFile, "%d", *temp);
```

but it doesn't properly work, I don't know why.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

Comment: "It doesn't properly work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: You cannot use `fscanf` with a binary file. Or, you can but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where do you make use of the size of the element during the read operation?

Comment: NB: binary-search is not what you think, it is an algorithm to search in O(log(n)) a value in a sorted array, I removed it from the tags. If you want to learn more about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: Why are you using dynamic memory to allocate 1 instance of FILETIME.  You could use a single variable instead (avoids memory leaks).  Or you could use `std::vector<FILETIME>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your offset with fseek, and then read len of bytes with fread:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = fopen("read_bytes.c", "rb");
    size_t offset = 0x001C;
    size_t len = 8;

    fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET);
    FILETIME* temp = malloc(sizeof(FILETIME));
    fread(temp, 1, len, file);
}
```

Comment: Why do you memcpy with a hardcoded length if you already have the length in a variable? Why do you read in a buffer and then use memcpy instead of directly reading?

Comment: I don't have the FILETIME header, it was to test it, I edited to remove the memcpy and stick to OP's question

Comment: `FILETIME` is a binary structure, so you can not print it with `%s`.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the problem was that I was using fscanf instead of fread. Thanks a lot